# Python Numpy: how to get the fraction of the frequency of a specific number in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to find the fraction of ones in a specific row or column of an array and make a new array of these fractions.

so far i have :

```
def calc_frac(a,axis=0):
    """a function that returns the fraction of ones in each column or row"""
    s=np.array(((a==1).sum())/len(a))
    return(s)
```

and all my test values are coming back false when they should be true

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? In Python 2, this won't work, because you use integer division. Since the numerator is almost always smaller than the denominator, the result with integer division is always 0. In Python 3, division is always done as floating point numbers, unless you specifically use the `//` division operator. A simple solution is to use `from __future__ import division` at the top of your program: this works in Python 2 and 3 safely, and both the `/` and `//` operators now behave the same (the Python 3 behaviour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no missing values in the array, you could just call `mean` method on the `a == 1` logical array, which returns fraction of 1s:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,0,2,2], [2,2,1,1]])
a
#array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
#       [1, 1, 1, 1],
#       [1, 0, 2, 2],
#       [2, 2, 1, 1]])
```

1) Fraction of 1s per column

```
(a == 1).mean(0)
# array([ 0.75,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75])
```

2) Fraction of 1s per row

```
(a == 1).mean(1)
# array([ 0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ])
```

---

If `nan` counts as an entry, the above method still works; if `nan` doesn't count as an entry, you could take care of `nan` as follows:

```
(a == 1).sum(axis)/(~np.isnan(a)).sum(axis)
```

Where *axis = 0*, fraction per column; *axis = 1*, fraction per row.